# Redeem Coupon Form Inside Expresso Store Checkout

Tags: expresso-store, checkout, ee, act

I am using expresso store as my checkout form (which is already using the checkout & product tags to wrap the products inside of the cart), but need an additional form which consists of a simple textbox and button inside of these tags which will redeem a specific coupon. If I use the  HTML tag, the button to go to the next step does not work (as there are now two forms on the page). How would I be able to include this form and then link the 'Redeem' button to a function that I already have in my module? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow Justin's good advice for coupon redemption using the built-in Store functionality. See [Update Cart](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#update_cart) on the Checkout Tag Docs.

> How would I be able to include this form and then link the 'Redeem'
>   button to a function that I already have in my module?

Then along *with* using the native update cart function you can run your own method when a coupon is redeemed by putting your method in an *extension* that uses one of Store's Hooks. See Store's [Order Update Hooks.](https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#order_update_hooks)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add a field for the coupon code into your existing HTML form for the checkout then just include an update cart button next to the coupon code input.