# Linking an ACT ID To A Module Function

Tags: ee2, checkout, act

Currently I have a function called `redeem_coupon()` in one of my modules in a EE2 project. I also have the button in a `<form>` element to link the function to. I know I have to add the function to the database table called exp_actions. I have the following code for the button:

```
<form action="./" name="redeemcouponform">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="couponcode" maxlength="12"/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="APPLY" class="button tiny success" /></td> </tr>
  </table>
  <input name="ACT" value="{AID:Lb_cart:redeem_coupon}" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Is there any specific way I need to connect the button to the ACT so it can fire the function when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a form on the front end, is that correct?

Assuming it is, and assuming clicking the button submits the form in the usual way, you just need to set the `action` attribute on your opening `form` tag to be a URL that includes the appropriate Action ID (the one tied to the `redeem_coupon()` method in your module).

The front end Action URL should look something like `http://example.com/index.php?ACT=123` where the "123" is your Action ID. You'll want to set that ID dynamically and it looks like you already have a method for doing that (guessing by the `{AID:Lb_cart:redeem_coupon}` tag in your example).

For a good primer see [A Brief Introduction to ExpressionEngine ACTions](http://experiencehq.net/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-expressionengine-actions)

If this form is in the control panel then the idea is similar, but the approach is a little different. Let me know if this form is in the Control Panel not the front end and I will update my answer.

Comment: PS I see from your [other question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/redeem-coupon-form-inside-expresso-store-checkout) that you might be trying to integrate your coupon function with Expresso Store. If that's the case you may want to consider creating an extension tied to one of [Store's Extension Hooks](https://exp-resso.com/docs/v1/extension_hooks.html) to call your method.

Comment: Hello, yes this is a form in the front-end and I am using store yes. So I can't use a normal form for this with store in the checkout stages, but rather create an extension?

Comment: You can. This separate-form approach should work in any of your templates. But creating a Store extension that runs when one of Store's forms is submitted might be a little easier and streamlined.

Comment: @AlexKendrick Sorry to bring up an old thread, but can you tell me how to do an ACT in the control panel?

Comment: Hi Don. Please post a new question with more detail about what you are trying to accomplish. Too tricky to handle via comments.